# Как int (число) превратить в char (строку) в СИ

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, pic

Пытаюсь перенести int(число) в char(строку).
Использую такой код :

```
int adcResult = 333;

char h = (char)adcResult;
char h1 = (char)ADC1BUF0;
сhar h2= itoa(adcResult);

puts_lcd( h2   ,3); // из за этой строки не собирается ошибки пишет ;_;
...

...
void puts_lcd( unsigned char *data, unsigned char count ) 
{
    while ( count )
    {
        lcd_data( *data++ );
        count --;
    }   
}
```

Но он выводит на экранчик отладочной платы(Explorer 16) полную белиберду.

Библиотека `#include <iostream.h>` не поддерживаеться.
В связи с тем что программа пишется в MPLAB для микроконтроллера семейства dsPIC33 (почему то не поддерживает эту библиотеку).

Comment: `atoi` объявлен в `<stdlib.h>`

Comment: @acade поправил

Comment: А сколько там бит в байте? 256 — это 0 mod 256.

Comment: @bipll поправил

Comment: @timob256, `stdlib.h` тоже не поддерживает?

Comment: Так в char или в строку? Это разные вещи. Сорри, с первого раза ниасилил заголовок. :-\

Comment: @bipll оба варианта меня устроят

Comment: @timob256, вам нужен аналог `itoa`?

Comment: Попробуй использовать символы от 0 до 255

Comment: @acade `stdlib.h` да подерживает

Comment: `itoa` принимает первым параметром число, которое необходимо перевести, вторым указатель на `char`, куда следует поместить результат и третьим параметром систему счисления.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/).

Первый параметр: число которое необходимо преобразовать в строку (int)

Второй параметр: указатель на строку, куда необходимо записать преобразованное число.

Третий параметр: Система счисления, по которой происходит перевод числа

Использование функции `itoa` в вашем случае:

```
int adcResult = 333; // исходное число
char adcString[15];  // буфер, в которую запишем число
itoa(adcResult, adcString, 10); // вместо третьего параметра
                                // можете написать нужное вам значение
                                // например перевести в 16-ричную с.счисления
```

`puts_lcd` необходимо вызвать следующим образом:

```
puts_lcd(adcString, strlen(adcString));
```